# Does Power Pact of Spirit Pact quality use character or spirit ability?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

On page 108 of Street Magic, the Power Pact quality, it allows the character to use one of the  spirit's powers.  What it doesn't specifically say is the strength of the power when wielded by the character.  Is this power treated at the same level as the spirit's Force, or is it linked to an attribute on the character, such as Magic?

I would like to know if there is an errata or anything that specifies this?  Short of that, I would certainly entertain house rules and their justifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is answered in the FAQ, kinda.

The Endowment spirit power is very similar to Power Pact, and similarly doesn't specify whether you use your own stats or the Spirit's stats.  The FAQ has this to say on the subject.

> **Q:** Can a spirit with Endowment use it to grant a character Materialization?
>
> **A:** A spirit with Endowment can share any power it possesses. When using the power the character uses the spirit’s attributes for any tests necessary for the power, as the power originates from the spirit.

It seems pretty reasonable to me that since you are using the *spirit*'s power, not gaining a spirit power for yourself, you'd use it's Force.  It's loaning you *it's* power, not giving *you* the ability to perform something similar using your Magic or whatnot.